# Java application: How to play sound

Tags: java

Hello I have a game that has a title menu and I want to play music in the title menu. The game is an application NOT an  applet. *(and I'm not changing it)* I saw a video where he uses sun.audio pckage, But when I tried it I got an error when I was writing the code. Access restriction it says. Do I have to download files or what do I need to do.

Comment: Please review the [help] before asking further questions. You've asked a number of off topic or unclear questions and you will be restricted from asking questions on the site if this pattern continues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For decent sound support, the standard approach in Java engines is to use [OpenAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenAL). Aside from being fuller-featured, this will solve your problems with access restrictions, implicitly.

OpenAL is found in wrappers like [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org) and engines like [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) and [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com). It is the *de facto* standard for sound in games across languages and platforms.